# Python socket error occured

Tags: python, sockets

I wrote this code.

```
import socket

host = 'localhost'
port = 3794
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind((host, port))
while 1:
        print 'Type message you want to send...'
        msg = raw_input()
        if msg == '':
                s.close()
                break
    s.sendall(msg)
```

and next execute this code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket.py", line 11, in ?
    s.bind((host, port))
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: (99, 'Cannot assign requested address')
```

What's wrong?

Do you know solutions?

Comment: I tried the code it says: UDP sockets don't have sendall() method.

Comment: I executed that code and it runs fine (though there's no socket listening). But the indentation is wrong in 's.sendall(msg)'.

Comment: @ffffff, please show us complete code, specifically where you specify your endpoint (as by connect()).  Under py2.4, this fails for me with EDESTADDRREQ ("Destination address required").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This means that you already have a socket bound to 3794 port.

It may be another application or it means that port didn't got released yet after the previous run of your own script (it happens, if script terminated improperly).

Simply try to use another port number - I believe everything will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem and it was caused by trying to listen on the wrong host.  When I changed it to an IP that was actually associated with the machine the code was running on (localhost), the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes up mostly due to the the port being already used by another application/service .
Choose a port number above the range of registered ports , i.e 49151