# Python urllib2: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, proxy, python-2.7, urllib2

I am sending thousands of requests using `urllib2` with proxies. I have received many of the following error on execution:

```
urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305050/python-socket-error-occured) that it may be due to a socket already being bonded. Is that the case? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the exact code you are using, and include the full backtrace of when it fails?

Comment: your problem looks similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190595/repeated-post-request-is-causing-error-socket-error-99-cannot-assign-reques

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer to a similar looking question that I prepared earlier.... much earlier...
[Socket in use error when reusing sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436261/21945)

The error is different, but the underlying problem is probably the same: you are consuming all available ports and trying to reuse them before the TIME_WAIT state has ended.

**[EDIT: in response to comments]**

If it is within the capability/spec for your application, one obvious strategy is to control the rate of connections to avoid this situation.

Alternatively, you could use the [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#module-httplib) module. `httplib.HTTPConnection()` lets you specify a `source_address` tuple with which you can specify the port from which to make the connection, e.g. this will connect to localhost:1234 from localhost:9999:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost:1234', source_address=('localhost',9999))
conn.request('GET', '/index.html')
```

Then it is a matter of managing the source port assignment as described in my earlier answer. If you are on Windows you can use this method to get around the default range of ports 1024-5000.

There is (of course), an upper limit to how many connections you are going to be able to make and it is questionable what sort of an application would require making thousands of connections in rapid succession.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. As you said, the error is not the same. I am not actually using the socket library in my application. I am using urllib2 and gevent for many asynchronous connections. Do you know how I can implement this solution using those libraries instead of the socket library?

Answer (score 2):

As *mhawke* suggested, the issue of `TIME_WAIT` seems most likely. The system wide fix for your situation can be to adjust kernel parameters so such connections are cleaned up more often. Two options:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1
```

This will let the kernel reuse connections in `TIME_WAIT` state. This may cause issues with NAT setups. Another one is:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans=8192
$ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries=1
```

This tells the kernel to keep at most `8192` connections not attached to any user process and only retry once before killing TCP connections.

Note that these are not permanent changes. Add the setting to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make them permanent.

http://code.google.com/p/lusca-cache/issues/detail?id=89#c4
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.kernel.obscure.html

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue but was using POST command using python's request library though!!
To make it worse, I used multiprocessing over each executor to post to a server. So thousands of connections created in seconds that took few seconds each to change the state from TIME_WAIT and release the ports for the next set of connections.

Out of all the available solutions available over the internet that speak of disabling keep-alive, using with request.Session() et al, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511852/7103409) answer to be working which makes use of 'Connection' : 'close' configuration as header parameter. You may need to put the header content in a separte line outside the post command though.

```
headers = {
        'Connection': 'close'
}
with requests.Session() as session:
response = session.post('https://xx.xxx.xxx.x/xxxxxx/x', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
results = response.json()
print results
```

Just give it a try with request library.