# Python-console not working in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

[image]

I get this error, when I try to run Python console from PyCharm. What does it mean? And how can I fix it?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can't see your error. You forgot it?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE see image

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Did you see image ?  Can you help me ?

Comment: The error I see, claims that the application cannot assign the requested address (from socket operations). Did you check existing question and answer pages like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246103/socket-errorerrno-99-cannot-assign-requested-address-and-namespace-in-python already?