# OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address - py

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu

I just copied this code for a client/server example:

http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_server_client.php

and when I run the code I get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Server:

```
# server.py 
import socket                                         
import time

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 9999                                           

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)                                           

while True:
    # establish a connection
    clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()      

    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
    currentTime = time.ctime(time.time()) + "\r\n"
    clientsocket.send(currentTime.encode('ascii'))
    clientsocket.close()
```

Client:

```
# client.py  
import socket

# create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 9999

# connection to hostname on the port.
s.connect((host, port))                               

# Receive no more than 1024 bytes
tm = s.recv(1024)                                     

s.close()

print("The time got from the server is %s" % tm.decode('ascii'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `host = socket.gethostname()` with `host = '127.0.0.1'` and it should work.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246103/socket-errorerrno-99-cannot-assign-requested-address-and-namespace-in-python)

Hope this wil help :)