# Server- Server communication Python socket- OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have tried to create a simple socket program where I can enable back and forth communication between two server sockets. The first iteration runs successfully and then there is one set of message passing that is possible. When it comes to second round of message passing I get the error.
I feel there is some mistake in the IP Address but I could not resolve it.

I have looked here but could not find a solution

[OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address - py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286678/oserror-errno-99-cannot-assign-requested-address-py)

[Python - socket.error: Cannot assign requested address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306528/python-socket-error-cannot-assign-requested-address)

Any help is deeply appreciated

#### This is Server 1:

```
import socket 
import requests

host = "127.0.0.1"
#ip address
port_other_send = 5007
#Other's port while sending
port_own_send = 5006
#Our port for sending
port_other_recieve = 5009
#other port for recieving 
port_own_recieve = 5008
#our port for recieving
#s = socket.socket()
#s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
#s.bind(("", port_own)) 


#binds the socket element to the IP address and the Port    

def main():

    send()

def send(): 
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((host, port_own_send))
    s.connect((host,port_other_recieve))
    message = input("Type message to be sent ")
    while message != "q":   
        s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        break   
    receive()
def receive():
    print("This works yo")
    socketva = socket.socket()
    socketva.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    socketva.bind((host, port_own_recieve)) 

    socketva.listen()
    c,addr=socketva.accept()
    x = True
    while x ==True:
        print("Connection from",(addr))
        data = c.recv(1024)
        print ("Data recieved ", str(data))
        response= ("Data recieved")
        c.send(data)
        x = False
    c.close
    send()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### This is server 2:

```
import socket 
import flask

host = "127.0.0.1"
#ip address
port_other_send= 5006
#Other's port while sending
port_own_send= 5007
#Our port for sending
port_other_recieve = 5008
#other port for recieving 
port_own_recieve=5009
#our port for recieving 

#binds the socket element to the IP address and the Port

def main():

    receive()

def receive():
    socketva = socket.socket()
    socketva.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    socketva.bind((host, port_own_recieve)) 

    socketva.listen()
    c,addr=socketva.accept()
    x = True
    while x== True: 
        print("Connection from",(addr))
        data = c.recv(1024)
        print ("Data recieved: ",data)
        response= ("Data recieved")
        c.send(data)
        x= False
    c.close
    send()

def send():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((host, port_own_send))
    s.connect(("",port_other_recieve))  
    message = input("Enter reply message ")
    while message != "q":   
        s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))         
        receive()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

#### Server 1 Output:

```
Type message to be sent hi
This works yo
Connection from ('127.0.0.1', 5007)
Data recieved  b'hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Server_socket.py", line 100, in <module>
    main()
  File "Server_socket.py", line 57, in main
    send()
  File "Server_socket.py", line 68, in send
    receive()
  File "Server_socket.py", line 87, in receive
    send()
  File "Server_socket.py", line 63, in send
    s.connect((host,port_other_recieve))
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

#### Server 2 Output:

```
Connection from ('127.0.0.1', 5006)
Data recieved:  b'hi'
Enter reply message hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Server_socket2.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "Server_socket2.py", line 23, in main
    receive()
  File "Server_socket2.py", line 41, in receive
    send()
  File "Server_socket2.py", line 50, in send
    s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))         
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Why do you set `socket.SO_REUSEADDR`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380057/python-binding-socket-address-already-in-use                                                                                                                         I was getting the address already in use error which was rectified by this.

Comment: OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
When I don't set it ,I get this.

Comment: You get "this" when two processes are listening to the same host/port combination. This should happen in special setups only. Like if you have two servers serving the same port for redundancy.

Comment: So, what do you recommend ?