# OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: centos, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Trying to run `jupyter notebook` on a CentOS 7. It comes back with:

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

And the stack trace:

```
[user@desktop ~]$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/use/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(notebook.notebookapp.main())
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1296, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1120, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 142, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 197, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Comment: `jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8888` got things going for me. the error was likely caused because the default ip/port that it was previously trying to assign was already taken.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8888
```

I had to simply set the ip/port params. The issue was likely caused because the default ip/port that it was previously trying to assign was already taken!

Answer (score 6):

In a remote VM, I solved the issue by

```
$ jupyter-notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888
...
    
    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://0.0.0.0:8888/?token=1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  (the token is for demo)
    
...
```

Note: do not assign the specific ip

then I can connect to jupyter notebook via:

```
http://your_vm_ip:8888/?token=1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

(replace `0.0.0.0` with `your_vm_ip`)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a permanent solution.

1. Create a configuration file for Jupyter, enter in the terminal: `jupyter notebook --generate-config`
2. The last command will create a file in **/home/USER/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py**
3. Open the file **jupyter_notebook_config.py** and edit the variable **c.NotebookApp.ip** as follows:
   `# c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'`
   `c.NotebookApp.ip = '127.0.0.1'`
4. Enter in the terminal: `jupyter notebook`

Remarks: sometimes need to first chmod to grant permissions, the file

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried several ports already (using `--port XXXX`), and none work:

Check that the `localhost` entry in `/etc/hosts/` is not set to something other than `127.0.0.1`.