# server_socket.bind(sa) failure

Tags: python, networking

On Ubuntu service, I want to setup shadowsocks service. I used the following command in order to install this package:

```
$ pip install shadowsocks
```

and then

```
$ ssserver -c /etc/Shadowsock.json
```

whereas the latter is giving me the following error:

```
$ ssserver -c /etc/Shadowsock.json 
INFO: loading config from /etc/Shadowsock.json
2018-11-16 16:06:44 INFO     loading libcrypto from libcrypto.so.1.1
2018-11-16 16:06:44 INFO     starting server at 3.0.103.80:8388
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ssserver", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('shadowsocks==3.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'ssserver')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shadowsocks/server.py", line 74, in main
    tcp_servers.append(tcprelay.TCPRelay(a_config, dns_resolver, False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shadowsocks/tcprelay.py", line 754, in __init__
    server_socket.bind(sa)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

The /etc/Shadowsocks.json is below

```
{
  "server":"3.0.103.80",
  "server_port":8388,
  "local_address":"127.0.0.1",
  "local_port":1080,
  "password":"dmlsgdsbhhh",
  "timeout":300,
  "method":"aes-256-cfb",
  "fast_open": false
}
```

Can anybody help me to investigate what may be the cause for this exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [socket.error:\[errno 99\] cannot assign requested address and namespace in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246103/socket-errorerrno-99-cannot-assign-requested-address-and-namespace-in-python)

Comment: anybody can give some suggest?

Comment: maybe you can change server value in /etc/Shadowsocks.json to localhost and test if it works

Answer (score -2):

```
"server":"0.0.0.0",
```

Comment: It's better to add some details around your answer.

Comment: The answer is correct. More explanation certainly could have helped. Basically if you're starting the server program, the "server address" would naturally be the localhost, instead of the public IP of the VPS.