# Exception occured while running corda node on virtual machine on google cloud

Tags: java, networking, kotlin, corda, bootstrapper

All the steps followed by Deploying a node to a server. Failure in initialisation [errorCode=1tpqp1v, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/1tpqp1v]
 Exception during node startup: bind(..) failed: Cannot assign requested address [errorCode=1tpqp1v, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/1tpqp1v]

Comment: there is not enough information here to help you. I can assume that "Cannot assign requested address" is due to a port issue.

Comment: @DanNewton When we are using localhost for (p2pAddress,address,adminAddress) then it is working fine on virtual machine but i have changed these address into ip that provided us through cloud then excpetion occured. Can you please let us know if we are doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: can you show me your config

Comment: @DanNewtonPlease have a look into node.conf devMode=true
myLegalName="O=Google,L=New York,C=US"
p2pAddress="34.66.210.231:10008"
rpcSettings {
    address="10.128.0.6:10009"
    adminAddress="10.128.0.6:10049"
}
security {
    authService {
        dataSource {
            type=INMEMORY
            users=[
                {
                    password=test
                    permissions=[
                        ALL
                    ]
                    user=user1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Comment: can the machine your on access `34.66.210.231` and `10.128.0.6`? I also feel like `10.128.0.6` should actually be `localhost`.

Comment: @DanNewton Through telnet i have checked and it's connected. It seems node started for a time then stopped

Comment: "Cannot assign requested address" is not port issue. its caused by trying to bind address which host does not have. 

this question and its answer may be helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246103/socket-errorerrno-99-cannot-assign-requested-address-and-namespace-in-python

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57220346/1982282

cluster-ip of kubernetes service object and gcp global ip assigned to GLB are example of ip which __may point to your node__ but __your node does not own__.

if you try to bind the server on such ip, "Cannot assign requested address" may happen.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue related to the node's RPC settings.

Try changing the address and adminAddress of your node's RPC settings to 0.0.0.0, leaving the port untouched. For example:

```
rpcSettings {
    address="0.0.0.0:10009
    adminAddress="0.0.0.0:10049"
}
```

These addresses do not need to be accessible from other nodes, as they are solely used by the node itself during start-up.